# WKHTMLTOPDF slow pdf generation

Tags: php, performance, laravel, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to generate PDF's for invoices and stuck on it. The problem is all pdf libraries i've tried so far are extremely slow: TCPDF ~40 sec to generate pdf file and DOMPDF took more then minute - then i shut it down.

I'm using Laravel 5.3 + PHP 7.1 on Windows machine, and trying this library - https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy

Simple test takes about 3-4 sec:

```
$html = $view->render();
$pdf = App::make('snappy.pdf.wrapper');
$pdf->loadHTML('<h1>Test1234</h1>');
return $pdf->download();
```

And same invoice generation like 8-10 sec.

Script has 256MB memory limit and pc is on i7 cpu.

**How can i tune up it's performance?**

Comment: I assume you are already using the latest version of those PDF libraries? The memory limit is irrelevant as long as you are not hitting it; PHP will not keep track of it's usage and try to juggle it's memory usage to stay under your limit. HTML-based PDFs will **always** be slow because the library has to interpret it into PDF code. Using the `Cell()` and `MultiCell()`functions will always yield the best performance. https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_004/

Comment: I have also noticed that `<tr nobr="true">` will slow things down quite a bit but I would imagine that having your rows break across two different pages is not desirable.

Comment: Yea, i know that it won't be blazing fast, but still 10 seconds for 1 page in pdf with simple table and 2 small images, that's kinda too much...

Comment: I think it would be beneficial if you could present the code which takes 10 seconds for one page. You mention three different libraries and two code scenarios so it's really hard to provide any specific insight. I have a script which takes a total of 0.4 seconds for a single page (using TCPDF) which is a fairly complex HTML table and gets data from a database so your numbers seem strangely inflated.

Comment: Do you have some bootstrap css import in the page? The presence of this slows down generation.